# Каждое изображение меньше предыдушего

Tags: javascript, изображения

Имеется массив из 5 изображений, который отображается с помощью php:

```
foreach($top_images as $top_i) {
<br><img src="'.$top_i['url'].'" ><br>
}
```

В JavaScript'e совсем новичок, прошу совета, как сделать JavaScript'ом, чтобы каждое изображение было на 10% меньше предыдущего.

Прилагаю мой код (который, естественно, не работает):

```
foreach($top_images as $top_i) {
    echo '#'.$ratio;
    echo '

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var img = new Image();
                img.src = "'.$top_i['url'].'";
                img.onload = function() {
                    var width = this.width;
                    var height = this.height;
                    ratio = '.json_encode($ratio).';
                    this.width = this.width - this.width * ratio/10;
                    this.height = this.height - this.height * ratio/10;
                    //img.css("width", width - width * ratio/10);
                    //img.css("height", height - height * ratio/10);
                }
                });
        </script>
    ';
    $ratio++;
}
```

Comment: А зачем менять через JS, если можно на самом PHP им сделать разный Wisth x Height? Даже если через JS, то проще их опять же вывести с уникальными атрибутами class или id, выцепить через DOM и изменить Width x Height. То, что сейчас, похоже просто на усложнение задачи.

Comment: Предложено отличное решение:

http://jsfiddle.net/78hdpkzr/

Comment: @arggw, только не забудьте их в блок засунуть при надобности, что бы оно не распространялось на все картинки, которые только есть на странице, с соответствующими изменениями: http://jsfiddle.net/78hdpkzr/1/